# Can somebody explain to me what this simple makefile does

Tags: makefile, c

I'm new to C and Make and was wondering if someone could help me by explaining what this code does.

```
CC = gcc
C_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra

all: eecs338

eecs338: eecs338.o
        $(CC) eecs338.o -o eecs338

eecs338.o: eecs338.c
        $(CC) -c $(C_FLAGS) eecs338.c

clean:
        rm -f eecs338 eecs338.o
```

Comment: [A Simple Makefile Tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)

Comment: [GCC and Make
Compiling, Linking and Building
C/C++ Applications](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

Answer (score 2):

Makefiles are usually organized like so:

```
target: dependency
    actions
```

where *target* is just a label, *dependency* is another target (or file; this can be many things), and *actions* are the commands to run, for that *target*, once the *dependencies* have been met.

So your Makefile has the "all" target (a general default target), which has a dependency on "eecs338_hw01", and no actions.  "eecs338_hw01" is itself a target, and *it* has a dependency on "eecs338.o".  Now this "eecs338.o" is a file name (*and* it's a target); the `.o` extension is for an *object file*, which usually means it has been compiled from *e.g.* a `.c` file.

Looking at the "eecs338.o" target, we see that it has a dependency on the "eecs338.c" file.  This tells `make` to see if that dependency file is present.  **And** this "eecs338.o" target has some actions, namely, to execute the command that compiles `eecs338.c` into `eecs338.o`.

Once the `eecs338.o` file is generated, it satisfies the dependency for the "eecs338_hw01" target, which then runs *its* action: a command to create a executable named `eecs338` from the `eecs338.o` object file.

Thus your Makefile provides a way to compile `eecs338.c` into the `eecs338` executable, using rules that can be added onto later.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me what those C_FLAGS do?

Comment: The `-Wall` flag tells the compiler to enable a bunch of different warnings; it's short-hand for many different compiler warning options (see the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for more details).  However, not **all** warnings are enabled by the `-Wall` flag.  The `-Wextra` flag tells the compiler to enable *even more warnings*, warnings not covered by `-Wall`.  These warnings are usually done for the developer's benefit, to ensure that they have addressed many common issues/warnings in the code being compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely follow the tutorial posted in the comment. However, it may be easier for you if someone walks you through it:

The first two lines define two macros, CC as the gcc compiler and C_FLAGS as the compile flags to be used.

all: ... means that if you type "make all", make will check if eecs338_hw01 is up to date and exists. If not, it will "make" it by calling itself on eecs338_hw01.

eecs338_hw01: eecs338.o
        $(CC) eecs338.o -o eecs338 means that if you type "make eecs388_hw01", make checks if the file eecs338.o exists and is up to date and then calls gcc's linker on eecs388_hw01.o to produce the binary file eecse338. Otherwise it calls itself on eecs338.o first:

eecs338.o: eecs338.c
        $(CC) -c $(C_FLAGS) eecs338.c means that make checks if eecs338.c exists and is up to date. If it is, it calls gcc with the above specified flags to preprocess, compile and assemble eecs338.c into eecs338.o.

The last two lines mean that if you call "make clean", make calls rm -f on the two files, deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

```
CC = gcc # macros/variable definitions
C_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra

all: eecs338 # rule 'all' with dependancy on eecs338
```

This tells make that in order to `make all` `make eecs338` has to be executed.
'Make' searches for rules for building 'eecs338', a rule can be simply a sourcecode file names 'eecs338.c' or a rule in Makefiles

```
eecs338: eecs338.o # rule eecs338, depends on eecs338.o
    $(CC) eecs338.o -o eecs338
```

Make tries to satisfy dependancy 'eecs338.o'. If this dependancy is satisfied, it will execute the commands below (`$(CC) eecs338.o -o eecs338`).
It is obvious that this command depends on the object file 'eecs338.o' but you need to tell make this of course.

```
eecs338.o: eecs338.c # again, rule to make eecs338.o
    $(CC) -c $(C_FLAGS) eecs338.c

clean: # a rule with no dependancies, just executes the command
    rm -f eecs338 eecs338.o
```

So you can think of make as using a dependancy-tree which is walked through by recursively calling `make`.

Additionally, if make reaches the leaves of the tree, and it's only dependencies are files, it will check for those files being modified. If this is *not* the case, 'Make' will not do anything but just exit return to it's caller, ie. go up one level in the tree and telling the caller that it hasn't done anything (ie. nothing changed).

The next node in the tree also only executes if any dependency has changed. Ie. if the source file 'eecs338.c' has not been changed, 'eecs338.o' is not rebuilt. Resulting from this, 'eecs338' is also not linked again, as none of its dependancies have changed.

Of course, if any of the files have been removed, it will rebuild even if nothing in the source has been edited ^^

There are also more advanced techniques to Makefiles (silencing output, special rules, special commands etc.). Some of them are GNU Make specific and thus shouldn't be used when you need high-compatibility.